# how to make interpolation and decimation vector length equal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wireless, telecommunication

I am trying to implement interpolation and decimation without using build in  functions of MATLAB for this purpose i follow the following sequence

upsampling->
filter->
handle fir filter delay

these three steps known as interpolation

filter->
handle fir filter delay->
downsample
these three steps known as  Decimation

In the above processing after handling group delay my overall symbols are reduced that create a problem to recover the same data that is the input of interpolation So what should i do to handle this problem.

My code is written below

```
idata=ones(1,100); %input symbols 100
nfilt=30;
upfac = 10;
alpha = 0.5;

xr = upsample(idata,upfac); %upconverted symbols which is 1000
h1 = intfilt(upfac,2,alpha);
y = filter(h1,1,xr);
delay = mean(grpdelay(h1));
y(1:delay) = [];            %filter delay discarded 19 symbols are remaining symbols are 981

[B,A]=fir1(30,1/10);

dec_filter=filter(B,A,y);  %down sample filter symbols are still 981
delay = mean(grpdelay(B));
dec_filter(1:delay) = [];  %delay is 15 and after handling delay symbols reduced to 966
dec=downsample(dec_filter,upfac); %after down sample remaining symbols are 96
```

Comment: To me it is not clear what exactly the problem is, please add an example that illustrates or explains what you mean by "over all symbols are reduced" and what your expected behavior should be?

Comment: For example if i have a symbols of 100 in the input of interpolation and interpolation factor is 10 then after interpolation my symbols became 1000, Handling of  filter delay symbols discard some symbols at start for example if discarded symbols are 20 then 980 symbols fed it into the input of decimation that also handle filter delay and then decimate it finally my symbols are less than the input

Comment: Pad your data at the end before you filter it, and then you can discard the padded part and end up with the correctly sized filtered data. Of course, the padded values may still influence your results.

Comment: @buzjwa what values should i pad? Should i copy the last values before filtering. Speaking form another way if i want to implement the same functions in verilog i have core of filter that accept input and give interpolation/decimation filtered output how values are padded in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid performing all those calculations manually by using the [decimate function](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/decimate.html). Given your upsampled data, all you have to do is to execute the following code:

```
upfac = 10;
nfilt = 30;

idata = ones(1,100);
xr = upsample(idata,upfac);
dec = decimate(xr,upfac,nfilt,'fir');
```